# .htaccess prepending additional '/' when redirecting to www.*

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using this snippet:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

to redirect non-www requests to www.domain.tld. The redirect is fine except when I access the domain like **domain.tld** i get redirected to **www.domain.tld//** (Note the second slash). And that occurs only if the query string is empty, if I add */test/123* to it I get a perfect redirection: **www.domain.tld/test/123/** as expected.

> What are the possible reasons and how could I fix it? 
>   What is the reason for this strange behaviour?

PS If you want to see the full VHost config, let me know :)

Comment: I think that might be the directive `DirectorySlash` interfering here – you request domain.tld, which refers to the root directory, but the slash is missing, so mod_dir steps into action … but deactivating this directive is not recommended, it will cause lots of other problems. You could try fixing this by checking the REQUEST_URI with a RewriteCond first – and only add $1 after the target if it’s not empty or something … (And btw., what you refer to as the query string is the _path_ component of the URL, the query string are the parameters after that, `?foo=bar`)

Comment: Yep, I will be using user-friendly URLs like `www.domain.tld/article/Hello-World` or something similar. And the www. is critical due to the fact that I will be using dynamic subdomains, and I need to be sure that there will be no errors in the application code. Please post me an example of how could I check if the path component is empty. I am not very familiar  with mod_rewrite :)